# Need to redirect .html page to itself without file type (html) at the end of request (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Well, i need my page to be available at adresses: `site.com/some_page.html` and `site.com/some_page/`
the solution is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$|!^(.*)/(.*)\.css$ $1.html
```

but there is one problem, single page is available at both of request as two different pages. 
how can i redirect `site.com/some_page.html` to `site.com/some_page/` with 301 redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_alias

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/some_page\.html$ /some_page/
```

Or using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^/?some_page\.html$ /some_page/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! But there can be a lot of pages via some_page.html and put every single page in .htaccess file, i think, not right. I decide to use disalow directive to make all html files disallow for the search robots. Hope it helps...